# os.startfile Working on Python2 but bringing up and error on Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I made a some quick code on Py2 which uses the os and time modules that opens a picture every 3 seconds 5 times in total and it works perfectly of Py2 but gives an error on Py3 which doesn't explain anything to me.

Error Here:

(unicode error) 'unicodeescape'codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

And here's the code:

```
import os
import time

times = 5
count = 0

print("This program has started")

while(count <= times):
    time.sleep(3)
    os.startfile("C:\Users\...\Picture.png")   # Truncated
    count += 1

else:
    print("Program has finished")
```

Comment: Could you provide the _full_ traceback?

Comment: This is all that comes up https://gyazo.com/88bdc0ef3daae9b34f4c25ee1151c2f5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3 wants to treat the `\Uxxxx` sequence in `C:\Users` as a unicode character. It's always a good idea when dealing with Windows paths (and their backslashes) to use [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), which will treat the backslashes as normal characters:

```
os.startfile(r"C:\Users\...\Picture.png")
```

Alternatively, you could escape the backslashes individually:

```
os.startfile("C:\\Users\\...\\Picture.png")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm pretty new to Python so didn't know about the raw strings thing. Hope you have a nice day :)